# Formatting R markdown kable for PDF / xelatex

Tags: r, r-markdown, xelatex

I am trying to format an R markdown table (kable) for exporting to PDF via xelatex.
See image below for what I would like to do:

1. Add some padding in the header above and below the header text
2. Remove the vertical lines inside the table

Everything else would ideally stay the same.
[image: Requested changes to table]

This is my code so far. I am using kableExtra to format the table. I assume "extra_css = "padding: 5px" isn't doing me much good since I'm not exporting to HTML, but I am wondering if there is a PDF alternative.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

top_n_projects <- data.frame(
  num = c(1, 2, 3),
  funding_source_AB = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"),
  year = c(2020, 2021, 2022), 
  project_title = c("TEST", "TEST", "TEST"), 
  recipient = c("RECIP1", "RECIP2", "RECIP3"), 
  TotalCost = c("Blah blah", "Blah", "Blah")
)

# Make title for table
header <- length(names(top_n_projects)) # Have to specify number of columns wide
names(header) <- "MY HEADER - TEST "

project_kable <- top_n_projects %>%
  kable(., "latex",
    col.names = c(
      "#", "Funder", "Year", "Project title",
      "Recipient", "Total funded"
    ), linesep = ""
  ) %>%
  # Format the header
  row_spec(0,
    bold = TRUE,
    background = "#d8f0ff",
    color = "black"
  ) %>%
  # allow for multiple rows for really long titles
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(4, width = "20em") %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "15em") %>%
  column_spec(6, width = "7em") %>%
  # Add header above table
  add_header_above(
    header = header,
    font_size = 14,
    background = "#6fcdf4", # Change background
    color = "white", # Change text color
    bold = T,
    extra_css = "padding: 5px"
  )
```